# Recursion relations for integrating Gaussian functions

Tags: python, algorithms, c++, numerical-modelling, polynomials

I'm trying to implement a numerical method used in quantum chemistry from scratch. I'm using [this](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jcc.540110809) paper as a reference. It's also available on Sci-Hub. So, the method requires calculating integrals of each spatial dimension (x, y, z) using recursive relations but I got completely lost on how it can be implemented in the code. Can someone, please, guide me?

[image]

Here, the authors suggest starting from term (11). The question that I'm having here is what do 0 arguments mean? Is this the starting member of a functional sequence?
After calculating that, how is it related to (15) and (16)? How do I use (11) to calculate (15) and (16)? Given both (15) and (16) correspond to 2nd and 4th arguments equal 0. I understand that (15) is used to "step up" in index 1 and (16) is used to step up in index 3, but how is it supposed to be implemented? It also seems to be a fair question, what exactly do *i*, *j*, *k* and *l* mean in this function if not the basis function number? What do values *n* and *m* mean, as well?

Eventually, the algorithm leads to calculating (19) and (18) with (18) being the final value of the term. But how does it result from (15), (16) and (11)?

[image]

I would be very grateful if one provides me some pseudocode or Python/C++ functions. The method has been implemented many times already, however it's usually either Fortran or very high-level C++ which I can't understand. Because I can't understand it I'm making it from scratch. It has to be a compact and a portable code.

Comment: Look for a Python package named pyquante. There you find also several C++ implementations of the multicenter Gaussian integrals. By the way: "*provide me some pseudocode*" and "*I'm making it from scratch. It has to be a compact and a portable code*" don't fit together. Either you can' implement it, then do it, or use available and well-tested routines.

Comment: Maybe I'm asking for too much. 

Looking at PyQuante sources, it's even more confusing. The procedures that are said to be recursive in the paper do not look recursive in PyQuante at all. And they used primarily void functions when writing the code which makes not much sense when using C++.

It is also not clear what exactly is being done in the code because they referenced two papers on the method at once and those papers differ in notation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm not a fan of questions of the form "The codes I can find are too complicated for me, can someone please write a simpler code for me".

Comment: 1) Libint is indeed VERY complex and based on another method. 
2) There's also BAGEL, also VERY complex as it's mainly computer algebra generated.
3) GAMESS code base is mainly ancient and saw mammoths. Only a handful of people know how it works and can explain. I wouldn't expect to meet any of them.
I've finished writing my own code and now I actually understand how things work. I hoped there would be someone who could explain me the logic behind the recursive relations in the paper that would help to write the code, but apparently people prefer saying "RTFM" over giving the actual help.

Comment: I'm not even mentioning NWChem. What's common among all quantum chemistry software - it's mostly written in Fortran which I can't use in my implementation. And particularly the integration methods used is an arcane knowledge covered very, very briefly.